# MikroORM: No Update Event Fired When Adding an Entity to a Collection

Tags: mikro-orm

In MikroORM, I have two entities, let's call them Entity A and Entity B, set up with a one-to-many relationship. Entity A has a Collection of Entity B instances. I'm using an event subscriber to listen for updates to Entity A.

When I add a new Entity B to the Collection on Entity A, no update event is fired for Entity A. However, when I remove an Entity B from the Collection, an update event is fired for Entity A.

My understanding was that both adding and removing items from a Collection would be considered changes to the state of the parent entity and thus trigger an update event.

Is this not the case? Is it expected behavior in MikroORM for no event to be fired when adding an item to a Collection? If so, could you explain the rationale behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not the case, collections don't represent any database column, they won't trigger any events on the owning entity.

A 1:m collection is virtual, an inverse side, when you work with it, it just propagates to the owner, which is the m:1 side - and that is what represents a db column, and will trigger events.

In other words, if you add an entity to 1:m collection, you are not modifying the owning entity anyhow, you just create the connection between them - and that is the M:1 relation on the entity you added.

Similarly, when removing entity from 1:m collection, it means you are disconnecting the two entities. By default, this means nulling the M:1 property, or when you enable `orphanRemoval`, then it means the entity will get removed instead of the FK being nulled.